# SQL How to Query Total & Subtotal

Tags: sql, vertica, subtotal

I have a table looks like below where day, order_id, and order_type are stored.

```
select day, order_id, order_type
from sample_table
```

| day | order_id | order_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-01 | 1 | offline |
| 2021-03-01 | 2 | offline |
| 2021-03-01 | 3 | online |
| 2021-03-01 | 4 | online |
| 2021-03-01 | 5 | offline |
| 2021-03-01 | 6 | offline |
| 2021-03-02 | 7 | online |
| 2021-03-02 | 8 | online |
| 2021-03-02 | 9 | offline |
| 2021-03-02 | 10 | offline |
| 2021-03-03 | 11 | offline |
| 2021-03-03 | 12 | offline |

Below is desired output:

| day | total_order | num_offline_order | num_online_order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-01 | 6 | 4 | 2 |
| 2021-03-02 | 4 | 2 | 2 |
| 2021-03-03 | 2 | 2 | 0 |

Does anybody know how to query to get the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `case` and `sum`:

```
select day, 
    count(1) as total_order
    sum(case when order_type='offline' then 1 end) as num_offline_order,
    sum(case when order_type='online' then 1 end) as num_online_order
from sample_table
group by day
order by day
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pivot the data.  A simple way to implement conditional aggregation in Vertica uses `::`:

```
select day, count(*) as total_order,
       sum( (order_type = 'online')::int ) as num_online,
       sum( (order_type = 'offline')::int ) as num_offline
from t
group by day;
```

Comment: I like your conciseness: simply CAST-ing a Boolean to INT to get counters of 0 vs. 1, and sum them.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `count` to aggregate values that are not null

```
select 
    day, 
    count(*) as total_order, 
    count(case when order_type='offline' then 1 else null end) as offline_orders,
    count(case when order_type='online' then 1 else null end) as online_orders 
from sample_table 
group by day 
order by day;
```